# what does librosa.stft do that makes it different?

Tags: fft, python, stft, numpy, librosa

My understanding of the Short Time Fourier Transform is that first I need to frame the signal and window it, after that apply an fft on these windowed frames. Using Librosa:

```
signal = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10.])
frame_length_ex = 4
hop_length_ex = 2
frames_ex = librosa.util.frame(signal, frame_length=frame_length_ex, hop_length=hop_length_ex)
window = librosa.filters.get_window('hamming', frame_length_ex, fftbins=False)
windowed_frames_ex = frames_ex * window
```

`windowed_frames_ex` is:

```
array([[0.08, 2.31, 3.85, 0.56],
       [0.16, 3.08, 4.62, 0.64],
       [0.24, 3.85, 5.39, 0.72],
       [0.32, 4.62, 6.16, 0.8 ]])
```

The next step would be applying the [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform):

```
np.fft.fft(windowed_frames_ex)
```

which results in:

```
array([[ 6.8 +0.j  , -3.77-1.75j,  1.06+0.j  , -3.77+1.75j],
       [ 8.5 +0.j  , -4.46-2.44j,  1.06+0.j  , -4.46+2.44j],
       [10.2 +0.j  , -5.15-3.13j,  1.06+0.j  , -5.15+3.13j],
       [11.9 +0.j  , -5.84-3.82j,  1.06+0.j  , -5.84+3.82j]])
```

but with `librosa.stft` which include all the above mentioned:

```
get_stft = librosa.core.spectrum.stft(signal, n_fft=frame_length_ex, hop_length=hop_length_ex, win_length=frame_length_ex, window='hamming', center=False)
```

I get this:

```
array([[ 6.32+0.j  , 10.64+0.j  , 14.96+0.j  , 19.28+0.j  ],
       [-2.92+1.08j, -4.76+1.08j, -6.6 +1.08j, -8.44+1.08j],
       [-0.16+0.j  , -0.16+0.j  , -0.16+0.j  , -0.16+0.j  ]])
```

which is a lot different, so my goal is understanding what calculation happens in `librosa.stft` that makes it produce a different result from mine.

Comment: Did you look at the source code of librosa? The result from np is correct at a first glance (by summing all point you can get the DC component).

Comment: i did but i'm struggling to find it in the source code, also this is my first time on this topic, i need the explanation on how librosa get those result for my assignment.

Comment: i did find that librosa calls for numpy's fft in the core.fft but didn't know what happens to it afterward

Comment: Use the debugger to step through and see where your implementation differs from librosa’s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close!

1. The window should be computed with the default `fftbins=True` argument (that creates a **periodic window**, appropriate for use with the FFT).
2. You have a **dimension problem** when computing the FFT:

   Your frames matrix has each frame in the **columns**:

   ```
   [[ 1.  3.  5.  7.]
    [ 2.  4.  6.  8.]
    [ 3.  5.  7.  9.]
    [ 4.  6.  8. 10.]]
   ```

   and your window is a **row** array:

   ```
   [0.08 0.54 1.   0.54]
   ```

   As is, you're applying this window to each row of your frames
   matrix, instead of applying it to each **column**. Reshape either
   the window or the frame matrix to apply the window appropriately:

   ```
   windowed_frames_ex = frames_ex * window.reshape(4,1)
   ```

   Then when you call the fft function, make sure to compute the fft on
   the appropriate axis (the columns):

   ```
   np.fft.fft(windowed_frames_ex, axis=-2)
   ```

   This gives:

   ```
   # Manual
   [[ 6.32+0.j   10.64+0.j   14.96+0.j   19.28+0.j  ]
    [-2.92+1.08j -4.76+1.08j -6.6 +1.08j -8.44+1.08j]
    [-0.16+0.j   -0.16+0.j   -0.16+0.j   -0.16+0.j  ]
    [-2.92-1.08j -4.76-1.08j -6.6 -1.08j -8.44-1.08j]]

   # STFT
   [[ 6.32+0.j   10.64+0.j   14.96+0.j   19.28+0.j  ]
    [-2.92+1.08j -4.76+1.08j -6.6 +1.08j -8.44+1.08j]
    [-0.16+0.j   -0.16+0.j   -0.16+0.j   -0.16+0.j  ]]
   ```

   The extra row is because you're calling a complex fft. You can use
   `rfft` instead which computes a real fft:

   ```
   np.fft.rfft(windowed_frames_ex, axis=-2)
   ```

Comment: thank you! this does work and i understand now. but i forgot to ask, what if i change the Center to True in librosa.stft ? i read it and it says that it will pad the edge of my signal with zeroes but i did try doing it manually and after applying fft to it, produced a different result for the padded value.

Comment: I suggest you do what I mentioned in my comment to your question: use the debugger to step through the Librosa implementation and verify at each processing step that you get the same outputs as your own implementation !